# Oil coming from the motor of a lawn mower

Tags: oil, smoke, lawnmower

In winter, I helped my grandparents remove the oil from the lawnmower. Last month, we put in a new filter. Oil has gotten into it from turning the mower to the wrong side a few times apparently. New oil and gas was put in (I don't know when it by whom. Supposedly by staff at the hardware store that sold the new filter.)
Today we put in the new filter and started it up. But white smoke was coming from the motor's exhaust together with oil. I've removed some of the oil since it seemed to be too much. However, the problem still stands. 
I'm have no idea what the cause could be. Can anyone in here help me?
The lawnmower is a AL-KO Highline 523 VS with a Briggs & Station 675ex series motor.

Comment: I had some white smoke come from my lawnmower when starting it after the winter.  After awhile it "cleared up" FWIW...

Answer (score 0):

Several potential problems come to mind:

1. There is too much oil in the crankcase.  Check the oil level and if it's not within the correct range either remove the excess or add until it's where it's supposed to be.
2. The engine has a problem with the valve seals, possibly just from age or from sitting around too long.  In most engines this is a relatively easy fix but you may need to have a mechanic do it.
3. Too much oil or oil entering the combustion chamber has damaged the piston or the rings and now oil is leaking into the engine and being burned.  This is a relatively major repair job.